# Has anyone reversed Wyze cameras?

Tags: disassembly, security

Has anyone looked at the hardware to see what processor they're using or disassembled the firmware?

Wyze claims to have opensourced their firmware but their github repository seems to be mostly binary files with a few scripts tossed in. Further, they admit to not being fully open in the readme file.

[At $20 for a 1080p IP camera](https://www.wyzecam.com/product/wyze-cam-v2/), the offer seems to be too good not to have some string attached. HIK Vision cameras were all the rage a few years back until they were caught phoning home.

Comment: This kind of question is a  pretty bad fit for our site. If you have a specific question about reversing the firmware, ask about that. Polls are rarely useful for anyone.

Comment: the firmware is available here: https://support.wyzecam.com/hc/en-us/articles/360010068231-Wyze-Cam-v2-Firmware. The binaries in the filesystem target a MIPS CPU